# Vetor de ponteiros em que cada elemento é uma fila

Tags: c, ponteiro

Olá.
Eu queria criar um vetor de ponteiros em que cada elemento apontasse para uma suposta fila, porém quando tento acessar o (vetor de ponteiros) -> (TAD fila) -> (vetor dentro do TAD fila), tenho problemas, ele não acessa.

Segue exemplo

```
typedef struct colegio { // vetor com 180 ponteiros
    void *vetor_filas[180];
} Colegio;

typedef struct registro_fila { // fila com um vetor de 20 espaços
    int qtd_pessoas[20];
} Fila;

Fila* criar_salas() { // criação do TAD fila, retorno ponteiro tipo Fila*
    Fila *nova_fila;
    nova_fila = (Fila*)malloc(sizeof(Fila));

    return nova;
}

void alocarColegiosSalas(Colegio *colegio) { // aloca as filas nos 180 vetores
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 180) {
        colegio->vetor_filas[i] = criar_salas();
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {


    Colegio *novosColegios;

    alocarColegiosSalas(novosColegios);

    int a = 1;
    novoColegio->vetor_filas[0]->qtd_pessoas[0] = a;
 // aqui ele pede um casting do tipo (Fila*) (warning), e avisa que não é uma estrutura nem união.

    printf("%d\n", novoColegio->vetor_filas[0]->qtd_pessoas[0]); 
// avisa que a estrutura é algo que não é um estrutura nem união.


}
```

Acredito estar fazendo algo errado nas estruturas, ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Ele não faz nada porque `novoColegio->vetor_filas[0]` tem tipo `void *`. `novoColegio->vetor_filas[0]` nada sabe do que `qtd_pessoas` se trata. Para melhorar o código, declare `Fila` antes de `Colegio` e declare, dentro de `Colegio`, `Filas* filas[180];` em vez de `void *vetor_filas[180];`.

Comment: Apenas reforçando o que @MarceloUchimura já disse, ponteiros do tipo `void*` não podem ser utilizados sem serem primeiro convertidos para outro tipo, pois o compilador não sabe de que tipo é o valor apontado. Por isso esta instrução `colegio->vetor_filas[i] = criar_salas();` não irá funcionar.

Comment: Olá @MarceloUchimura, eu fiz o que você disse porém sem usar um ponteiro para a estrutura, simplesmente Filas fila[180], e dessa maneira consegui inserir os meus dados, porém me surgiu outra dúvida, em que caso, no qual eu tivesse estruturas aninhadas, eu precisaria, numa "passada" de uma estrutura para outra, usar o ponteiro? Abs.

Comment: Para usar operador `->`, o que está à esquerda dele deve ser um ponteiro, e o que está à direita, um campo de struct.